# Cabinet hinge fastener

Tags: cabinets, hinges

[image: cabinet door with holes for hinge hardware]
We removed all of the hinges to paint our kitchen cabinets last week. We had an issue with the pie-corner cabinet door hinges, though. When we attempted to remove the screws from one side of the hinge that connects the two doors together, the heads kept breaking off.[image: broken hinge hardware]
It was the side of the hinge that is not inset into the cabinet door, it is just surface mounted. We found that they used some sort of anchor to secure them. There is a 3/8" hole drilled with a forstner bit, then there was a metal anchor with threads that goes into the hole. 2 of these metal anchors are connected via a plastic strip (which sits between the cabinet and hinge), one anchor each for the top and bottom of the hinge. Finally a screw is driven into the metal piece which secures the hinge to the anchors/cabinet.
I've searched possible combination of terms I can think of to find this fastener (cabinet, hinge, pie-corner, anchor, dowel, fastener, brace, reinforcement) to no avail. It's a Salice hinge but it doesn't appear to come with any of the salice hinges I've located online.
[image: cabinet hinge]
Any guidance someone can give to find these would be appreciated.

I've included pictures below. Note that I had to cut the plastic strip to get the hinges removed, but 2 anchors were connected to the plastic strip when it was secured to the cabinet door.

Comment: Google 'threaded insert' or 'insert nut'. Alternately, you can find (at cabinetry specialists) a plastic insert that'll hold a regular screw. "Cabinet hinge dowel insert" eg, https://www.build.com/product/summary/1210175 . I don't think you need to replace the wide plastic insert.

Answer (score 3):

Threaded insert was the term I was looking for. I didn't find an exact replacement with the plastic connector but I'm hopeful one of the generic replacements will do the trick. Thanks to @Aloysius Defenestrate